# Offensive word for people, who offend others

Tags: word-request

I wonder, is there an offensive English word (or phrase) for people who offend others?  I mean a word that translates literally as "a guy who offends people" and can not be applied to other circumstances, and anyone would see more than this simple meaning in it and would not like to hear it about himself or herself.

There is no such thing in my language, so I can not use translators here unfortunately.

Comment: @snailboat, I do not thinks so, "Appropriate for situation" is very subjective characteristic, I think any offensive word would be appropriate if somebody offence you, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @snailboat, short offensive phrase would work too. If you state that this does not exist, you can make an answer from it.

Comment: Are you asking about "people who offend others"? "people who offend against others"? "people who commit offenses against others"? or "people who are offensive to others"?  These phrases have different meanings in English.

Comment: Are you looking for an [offensive word](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/offensive_1), or a [critical](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/critical) word? An offensive word in English usually means something vulgar or not polite. I replaced the noun "offence" in your question with the verb closest in meaning, ["offend"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/offend). Please look it over and make sure that is what you intended to say.

Comment: @ColleenV, I am looking for a vulgar (not polite) word to make a person, who offended me (or anyone else in front of me) uncomfortable.

Comment: @Jasper, I think this is the first one. People who make others feel uncomfortable and achieve this using words.

Comment: Aren't you asking use to give you the term to describe the type of person that would would become if you used it? "A person that offends someone?" In my opinion, you should focus on describing the offensive actions and not the person. Most of the time just pointing out the bad behavior publicly will make them uncomfortable and you won't have to be vulgar.

Comment: As @ColleenV points out, a simple "That was uncalled for." or "How rude!" or "You owe her an apology." might be appropriate.

Comment: @ColleenV, Jasper, no, I want to be on the same "level" as they are.

Comment: Hmmm, OK, but I think the type of answer you're looking for would be flagged for moderator attention. You might try the "urban dictionary" site. There are many truly offensive names to call people there.

Comment: @ColleenV: Questions and answers about (and therefore using) offensive language are [considered appropriate for English.SE](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/253/referencing-the-existence-of-words-that-may-be-offensive) (they even have a tag `offensive-language`), so why not here?

Comment: The words are *flouter*, *jeerer* or *scoffer*. They all define a person who does not respect others and always jeer/comment them to defame them. I have many such guys around me and believe me, I call them all jeerers! :P

Comment: @NateEldredge Offensive language may very well be appropriate here - it certainly is on topic for ELU because those words are part of the English language. I guess my qualms about it are around _teaching_ folks vulgar language, as opposed to explaining something they've come across.

Comment: @ColleenV: Hmm, I have no such qualms.  Native speakers learn and use offensive language with great facility, and I don't see why non-native speakers should not want to do the same.  As one example, Jack Kerouac was not a native English speaker - but if he'd never learned offensive language, *On the Road* would not have the energy that it does.  But I suppose any further discussion should go to Meta.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have no qualms about folks learning to curse in multiple languages. I find Italian particularly expressive :) I'm just not sure ELL is the place to teach them. You're right that maybe it's a discussion for meta.

Comment: @ColleenV Do you speak Italian? I've started learning Italian (thus recent switch to new user name).

Comment: @pazzo The limited Italian I speak and understand is mostly vulgar. My husband's family is 2nd generation Scicilian and usually only revert to Italian when they're very emotional ;)

Comment: A mildly offensive word for a mildly offensive person: **jerk**. This includes those who offend unintentionally.  "He didn't mean it; he's just naturally a jerk."

Comment: What about _beep_? Or if you want to write that down, you may use **********

Comment: There are quite a few suggestions that aren't what I would consider vulgar (one I haven't seen, but consider appropriate, is 'boor').  If you want to lower yourself to their level (whether you should or not is another issue) and are willing to use two words you can always use a form of what can be considered the most flexible word in the English language.  To wit: "don't be such a fucking boor".

Comment: @EricNolan, thesaurus explains that boor = an unrefined, ill-mannered person. And this is much much wider range of meanings than "a person, who offend others"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "harasser" is someone "who makes others feel uncomfortable [by] using words", gestures, and touch.

A "stalker" is someone "who makes others feel uncomfortable" by persistently trying to interact with them, either by using information they thought was private, and/or after they had told the stalker to have no further contact with them.

As Arrowfar suggested, "lowlife" is an offensive term for a poor person who might have criminal intentions.

"Crook" is a mildly offensive term for a criminal.  For example, when Richard Nixon said, "I am not a crook", it immediately made many people think he was a "lowlife" and unworthy of being President.

"Mugger" is a factual (but still insulting) term for a criminal who robs people on the street or in alleys by force (or threat of force).

"Thug" is an offensive term for an intimidating, possibly criminal, person.  Many bodyguards and muggers are called thugs.

"Rapist" and "child molester" are factual terms for people who commit particular crimes.  Because these crimes are so abhorrent (especially to many imprisoned criminals), they are very insulting terms.  (Many criminals consider it honorable to harm or kill rapists and child molesters.)

Comment: I see you use word criminal in a lot of definitions. Does lowlife, for example, describe a **noncriminal** person, who just say offensive words to others, like teenagers do?

Comment: @kim123 -- Are you trying to "pick a fight"? If you use "fighting words", you need to know what kind of fight you are getting into, and against how many people.  You also need to know what quite a few "vulgar" and "cuss words" mean.  Some can be taken more than one way.  For example, "punk" can refer to a teenager that likes loud, disreputable music (such as "heavy metal") -- or it can refer to a weakling who is repeatedly raped in prison.

Comment: A lot of these definitions use "criminal" because I thought you might want a synonym for "offender" -- "a person who commits offenses against others".

Comment: "Lowlife" implies that the person might be criminal, but it has plausible deniability.  You can pretend that you did not mean to imply that a "lowlife" is a criminal.  But that pretense would seem cowardly -- which is not the effect you are after.

Comment: It's also worth noting that "thug" has recently picked up racial connotations in many areas.

Comment: None these words are particularly offensive.

Answer (score 7):

In American English, the concept you are trying to communicate is usually implied through context.  "Asshole" and "Jackass" both imply someone who is unpleasant to be around.  "Prick", "Dick", and "Tool" are all ways of saying someone is aggressively unpleasant to those around them.

"Don't be a dick" is a good way to tell people to knock it off when they are being offensive.

Comment: It's worth noting, those all are primarily used when you're talking to a male. If you want to offend a woman, there are much better words to use.

Comment: I would stick with the gender-neutral "asshole" if addressing a woman.  Most of the female-specific words have pretty strong misogynistic connotations, and it makes it confusing if you are angry at them for acting like a fool or just for being a woman.

Comment: Well, if the goal is to be "on their level", I don't think you've gone far enough. "Don't be a dick." isn't going to make most folks uncomfortable. It would probably be answered with "Whatever dude." I still don't think this is a question that can be answered well here.

Comment: All the offensive words used here denote a person who is jerk, stupid, ridiculous and **not** particularly defining a person who offends others.

Comment: @MaulikV I disagree. All of those words are used to describe someone who is aggravating in some way. This is the closest match to what the OP was asking for; much better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The slang term for someone who deliberately tries to provoke confrontation by being rude, and doing so just for sake of their jollies is **troll**.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the words: [transgressor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transgress?q=transgressor#transgress__24),  [offender](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/offender?q=%20offender),  [wrongdoer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wrongdoer?q=%20wrongdoer), or [culprit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/culprit).

Comment: +1. The meaning is correct, but are they really offensive? I do not see that dictionary marks them offensive or at least informal, like nigger, nerd, noob.

Comment: @klm123 Well, if you want 'offensive' then try 'lowlife'.